# Need help finding dead cell data *GAME OF LIFE*

Tags: c++, conways-game-of-life

I have done everything so far in regards to creating a class, and finding the stats of live cells and generating generations. I am just stuck on finding the stats for dead cell data in a specific row and column here is my client.cpp. I would like to some guidance to finish off this final piece in my code, I can provide anymore code if necessary.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cassert>
#include <fstream>
#include "boolmatrix.h"

using namespace std;

void readGrid(/*out*/ boolMatrix& life);
void getGenerations(/*out*/ int& numGenerations);
void determineNextGeneration(/*inout*/ boolMatrix& life);
//void determineFateOfSingleCell(/*in*/ const boolMatrix& life,/*out*/ boolMatrix& life2,/*in*/int row,/*in*/ int col);
void printResults(/*in*/ const boolMatrix& life);

int main()
{
    boolMatrix life;    //Used for file reading

    int numGenerations;

   /* life.print();       //Normal ADT Grid Display */

    readGrid(life);     //ADT / File Read Display


    getGenerations(numGenerations);

    for (int count = 0; count < numGenerations; count++)
    {
        printResults(life);
        determineNextGeneration(life);
        printResults(life);
    }



    //*NOTE: MULTI LINE COMMENTS ARE CLASS TESTING FUNCTIONS*


 /*   //populate a bool array using rand values for cell coordinates or positions
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        life.set(rand() % 20, rand() % 20, true);
    } */

   // cout << life.get(0,0) << endl;

   /* for (int row = 0; row < boolMatrix::NUM_ROWS; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < boolMatrix::NUM_COLS; col++) {
            cout << life.neighborCount(row, col); //calling an important function to look around a cell
        }
        cout << endl;
    } */

}

void readGrid(boolMatrix& life)
{
    int row, col;
    //readGrid - HINT source code below should be a read or get_input function
    ifstream infile("lifedata.txt");

    infile >> row >> col;
    while (infile)
    {
        //matrix[row][col] = true;
        life.set(row,col,true); //a setter class member function is needed here
        infile >> row >> col;
    }
    infile.close();
}

void getGenerations(/*out*/ int& numGenerations)
{
    cout << "Enter number of generations: ";
    cin >> numGenerations;
    cout << endl;
}

void printResults(/*in*/ const boolMatrix& life)
{
    life.print(); //calling the class print member function

    //calling three more class member functions
    cout<<"Total alive in row 10: " << life.rowCount(10) << endl;   //Determines total alive in specific row
    cout<<"Total alive in column 10: " << life.colCount(10) << endl;    //Determines total alive in specific column
    //cout << "Total dead in row 16: " <<
    //Total dead in col 1 = 16
    cout<<"Total alive in matrix: " << life.totalCount()<< endl;    //Determines total alive


    cout << endl;

}

void determineNextGeneration(/*inout*/ boolMatrix& life)
{
    boolMatrix b;

    for(int row=0;row<boolMatrix::NUM_ROWS;row++)
    {
        for (int col=0;col<boolMatrix::NUM_COLS;col++)
        {
            int count = life.neighborCount(row,col);

            if(life.get(row,col))
            {
                if(count > 1 && count < 4)
                    b.set(row,col,true);
            }
            else
            {
                if(count == 3)
                    b.set(row,col,true);
            }

        }
    }

    life = b;
}
```

boolMatrix.h

```
#ifndef LIFE_H
#define LIFE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cassert>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class boolMatrix
{
public:
    static const int NUM_ROWS = 20; //Static variable declaring row size
    static const int NUM_COLS = 20; //Static variable declaring column size
    boolMatrix();   //A default constructor
    void set(int row,int col, bool val);
    void print() const; //observers
    bool get(int row,int col) const;
    int totalCount()const;
    int rowCount(int row)const;
    int colCount(int col)const;
    int neighborCount(int row, int col)const;
private:
    bool matrix[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS];

};

#endif
```

boolMatrix.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cassert>
#include <fstream>
#include "boolmatrix.h"

using namespace std;

boolMatrix::boolMatrix()
{
    //initialize array - HINT source code below should be an initialize function
    for (int row = 0; row < NUM_ROWS; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < NUM_COLS; col++)
        {
            matrix[row][col] = false;
        }
    }
}

void boolMatrix::set(int row,int col, bool val)
{
    assert(row >= 0 && row < NUM_ROWS && col >= 0 && col < NUM_COLS);
    matrix[row][col] = val;
}

void boolMatrix::print() const
{
    //print contents of array after initialization - HINT source code below should be a print function
    //  cout << "  01234" << endl;
     cout << "  ";
     for(int col = 0; col < NUM_COLS; col++)
     {
         cout << col % 10;
     }
     cout << endl;
    for (int row = 0; row < NUM_ROWS; row++)
    {
        cout << setw(2) << row % 25;
        for (int col = 0; col < NUM_COLS; col++)
        {
           if (matrix[row][col])
            {
                cout << "*";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << " ";
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;
}

bool boolMatrix::get(int row, int col) const
{
    assert(row>= 0 && row < NUM_ROWS && col >= 0 && col < NUM_COLS);
    return matrix[row][col];
}

int boolMatrix::totalCount()const
{
    int count = 0;
    for(int row = 0; row < NUM_ROWS; row++)
    {
        for(int col = 0; col < NUM_COLS; col++)
        {
            if(matrix[row][col])
                count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int boolMatrix::rowCount(int row)const
{
    //assert
    assert(row >= 0 && row < NUM_ROWS);
    int count = 0;

    for(int col = 0; col < NUM_COLS; col++)
    {
        if(matrix[row][col])
                count++;
    }
    return count;
}

int boolMatrix::colCount(int col)const
{
    //assert
    assert(col >= 0 && col < NUM_COLS);
    int count = 0;

    for(int row = 0; row < NUM_ROWS; row++)
    {
        if(matrix[row][col])
                count++;
    }
    return count;
}

int boolMatrix::neighborCount(int row, int col)const
{
    assert(row>= 0 && row < NUM_ROWS && col >= 0 && col < NUM_COLS);
    int count = 0;

    if(row > 0)
        count += get(row - 1, col);

    if(row < NUM_ROWS - 1)
        count += get(row + 1, col);

    if(col > 0)
        count += get(row, col - 1);

    if(col < NUM_COLS - 1)
        count += get(row, col + 1);

    if(row > 0 && col > 0)
        count += get(row - 1, col - 1);

    if(row > 0 && col < NUM_COLS - 1)
        count += get(row - 1, col + 1);

    if(row < NUM_ROWS - 1 && col > 0)
        count += get(row + 1, col - 1);

    if(row < NUM_ROWS - 1 && col < NUM_COLS - 1)
        count += get(row + 1, col + 1);

    return count;
}
```

SAMPLE OUTPUT:

(ORIGINAL GRID) GAME OF LIFE BEGINS STATISTICS

*GRID NOT DISPLAYED HERE BECAUSE TOO MANY SYMBOLS*

```
Total alive in row 10 = 3
Total alive in col 10 = 4
Total dead in row 16 = 15
Total dead in col 1 = 16
Total alive = 101
Total dead = 299
```

Comment: Presumably you can get the dead count in a certain row but subtracting the live count in that row from the width of the matrix. Similar process for the column. Does that help?

Comment: trying to visualize what you're trying to say:

 creating a whole different variable like an integer and then using the count to subtract the width and vice versa for the column?

Comment: I can't see your `boolMatrix` class, so I don't know what methods it has, but I see this code `cout<<"Total alive in row 10: " << life.rowCount(10) << endl;` and I'm wondering if you couldn't write something like this `cout<<"Total dead in row 16: " << life.rowSize() - life.rowCount(16) << endl;`, where `rowSize` is a method that returns the width of the matrix. Of course I'm guessing that you have a method called `rowSize` but even if you haven't it would be easy to write one.

Comment: Basically I'm saying that since every cell is either alive or dead, you can just get the dead count by subtracting the live count from the total number of cells.

Comment: Let me update the post a bit to elaborate more on this

Comment: Post is now updated with more detail

Comment: So I don't see why my solution doesn't work. Just add `int boolMatrix::rowSize() const { return NUM_ROWS; }` to your class then the code in the comment above works. What do you think is the problem?

Comment: My instructor does not want us to add anything else to the class only the eight member functions that are there, I believe he wants us to do it in the main.cpp

Comment: Well `NUM_ROWS` is actually static and public so you can write  `cout<<"Total dead in row 16: " << boolMatrix::NUM_ROWS - life.rowCount(16) << endl;` No need to add anything to the class.

Comment: Got it all to work, Thanks john! You rock :D